# Why does this function return LinkedIn instead of Amazon?

Tags: python, function, local

Why does this function return LinkedIn instead of Amazon?

```
def hey(location):
        location = "LinkedIn"
        answer = "Welcome to " + location
        return answer
        
print(hey("Amazon"))
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're declaring `location` as `"LinkedIn"` inside the function.

If you want `"LinkedIn"` as default if there is no parameter input for `location`, try:

```
def hey(location="LinkedIn"):
    return "Welcome to " + location
```